# Cant stop SAConfettiView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a third party library called SAConfettiView. (https://github.com/sudeepag/SAConfettiView)

I can't figure it out why I can't stop the SAConfettiView animation. I only start it once.

Here is my code to start and stop the SAConfettiView.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    perform(#selector(confetti), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
}

@objc public func confetti(){
    let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    confettiView.type = .Diamond
    view.addSubview(confettiView)
    confettiView.startConfetti()
    perform(#selector(stopConfetti), with: nil, afterDelay: 4)
}

@objc public func stopConfetti(){
    confettiView.stopConfetti()
    confettiView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: If you use a third party library and your question is specific to that library, you should state that in your question. I edited your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```

Delete the word `let` and all will be well.

Comment: All might not be well, depending on how the confettiView instance variable is defined and initialized. If it's an IBOutlet that is linked to a view defined in the storyboard then the code posted would add a 2nd confettiView. It isn't clear if that's an implicitly unwrapped optional or what. We need more info

Comment: I am doing a simple slot machine app to my son. When you get jackpot it will start the confetti and stop it after 4 seconds. Maybe i code it the wrong way, but It works now and my son is happy :) Sorry for man bad English.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt says in his answer, the problem is with the line `let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)` in your function `confetti()`.

The word `let` tells the complier that `confettiView` is a new, local variable that only exists inside the scope of the current function. It does NOT set the instance variable `confettiView` that we assume you have presumably defined in your view controller.

Because you create a new local variable `confettiView` inside your function, the instance variable `confettiView` is nil, so the call to `confettiView.stopConfetti()` fails.

Actually, it isn't clear how your `stopConfetti()` function compiles. If confettiView is an implicitly unwrapped optional, as outlets usually are, that should crash.

Show us the declaration of your `confettiView` instance variable.

Comment: Do you mean this? =)
`var confettiView = SAConfettiView()`

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, but that code is pointless and should not be that way. You should make it an Optional: `var confettiView: SAConfettiView?` Note that there's no real point to adding and removing the `confettiView` when you start and stop it. I would instead suggest adding the `SAConfettiView` to your storyboard and wiring it up in an outlet, and then starting/stopping it but not removing it.